# How Should I Combine These Two SQL queries into one?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make an INNER JOIN statement that will join two tables, the Orders table and the Customer table, these both share the value/key of CustomerID. The Customer table has the information for which state a customer lives in. The Orders table has the information for which customer, according to their customer ID, bought which product. I need to find which products are the top 3 most popular in certain states. Please find the table descriptions images below, so you can understand what I mean.

Orders table:

[image]

Customer table:

[image]

How can I make this INNER JOIN statement and include the logical operators (and/or) to make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Order
ON Customer.CustomerID= Order.Customer_ID AND <conditions>;
```

Inner Join is just only 1 way of joining 2 tables. You can also join these two tables using `WHERE` closure  as follows,

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM Customer c, Order o
WHERE c.CustomerID = o.Customer_ID AND <condition>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the OP's question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.